# Elastic Beanstalk git clone error on the gem `searcher`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, web-deployment

Now I am trying to deploy an web app to AWS through Elastic Beanstalk. But when I deploy, a git clone error occurs because of the gem `searcher`. This gem is not in [rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org) but in the github because it was not tested enough as the author of the gem says she didn't make it public on purpose.

The gem is installed with no problem in my local ubuntu environment. But it isn't installed when deployed making the whole deployment fail.

The following is the line written on the Gemfile.

```
gem "searcher", github: "radar/searcher"
```

The following is a part of the error message when I deploy to AWS via Beanstalk CLI.

```
ERROR: [Instance: i-088606db918d932ff] Command failed on instance. Return code: 11 Output: (TRUNCATED)...und Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/radar/searcher.git'
```

As I said, the gem is installed well and no problem with git clone either in my local ubuntu machine as in the image below.

[image: No problem with git clone command in my local environment]

Answer (score 4):

I know it's a bit late, but I solved this by installing git on my EC2 instance.

Just ssh into your EC2 instance and type the following:

```
sudo yum install git
```

That should hopefully fix it.

Comment: This was a fix for me but instead of using ssh I did it through the  `.ebextensions` file

Comment: To add on to @kinduff excellent suggestion, [here are the docs for `.ebextensions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-packages)